# iPhone: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods not Invoked?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a camera controller based on a `UIImagePickerController`:

```
@interface CameraController : UIImagePickerController
    <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
    // <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
}

@end
```

Init generates a warning that `UINavigationControllerDelegate` is not implemented (it is expected since I don't want my object to be that delegate):

```
- (id) init
{
    if(!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    super.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    // Commenting delegat does not help
    super.delegate = self;

    return self;
}
```

Despite being a `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate, `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` *is not* called. I also verified the other two delegate methods are not being called either.

If I do claim adherence to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWith` *is* called but I crash on `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ASSERT_VALID(picker);
    ASSERT_VALID(info);

    // Commenting does not help
    [picker autorelease];

    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];   
    ASSERT_VALID(image);

    // Image processing commented out

    // super.delegate = nil;
    // picker.delegate = nil;

    // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // [super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // [self performSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
    // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    // [super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
}
```

I've looked at a number of posts on this CURSED view controller. The closest, [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate not responding properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363091/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-not-responding-properly) and [iPhone - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727895/iphone-uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-inheritance), did not help.

Any ideas what might be this time? Two questions immediately come to mind: (1) what does being a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` have to do with invoking my callback with the image, and (2) why can't this object clean itself up properly?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` class is not supposed to be subclassed. The reference manual says:

> This class is intended to be used
>   as-is and does not support
>   subclassing.

And there's no reason to. Just create a subclass of a `UIViewController` and implement the delegates.

I've successfully used it many times. I've always declared that my view controller implements `UINavigationControllerDelegate` but haven't implemented any of the methods of this protocol.

Comment: Thanks Codo. Its frustrating that I run with full warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) and Clang and did not get one complaint. I would have expected the static analyzer to produced an item. In general, I really miss the advanced analyzer in Visual Studio (SAL). (Not sure if it would have caught a similar issue, though).

Comment: `The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only.` Its funny how Apple hides the subclassing issue behind a discussion of portrait/lanscape modes. I stopped reading that paragraph immediately because I only support portrait mode. Assholes.